# How to calculate points on upper half of circle

Tags: c#, geometry

I'm trying to place some icons equally on the upper half of a circle.

I managed to place them around a whole circle with the following formula/code

```cs
for(int i=0;i<numberOfItems;i++)
{
    float x = (float)(center.X + radius * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * i / numberOfItems))-iconBmp.Width/2;
    float y = (float)(center.Y + radius * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * i/ numberOfItems))-iconBmp.Height/2;

    canvas.DrawBitmap(iconBmp, new SKPoint(x, y));
}
```

But I can't figure how to do it for just the upper half of the circle?
Is there a formula for that as well?
I have the feeling that the one I have for the whole circle just needs some adjustment to achieve that...but can't figure what.

Thank you already!

Comment: Does replacing numberOfItems with (2*numberOfItems) convert the functions to a half-circle?

Comment: use (2*numberOfItems) instead of  numberOfItems and If y > center.y then don't draw.

Comment: uhm .... assuming bottom left is 0:0 `if (y < lower_half) then { y += lower_half; }`
you are welcome

Comment: What's your coordinate system? How do you want the icons to be distributed (e.g., in case of 2: one left, one right or one left-up, one right-up)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a math question than a programming question.

**2pi radians = 360 degrees**

So if you want all of the items shown, but the shape to be a half circle, then use:

`Math.PI * i / numberOfItems` instead of `2 * Math.PI * i / numberOfItems`

Also because screen coordinates start in the top-left corner. That will make it the bottom half of the circle with the first item on the right. If you want the top half of the circle with the first item on the left, then just add pi:

`Math.PI + (Math.PI * i / numberOfItems)`

Whole code:

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfItems;i++)
{
    float x = (float)(center.X + radius * Math.Cos(Math.PI + (Math.PI * i / numberOfItems)))-iconBmp.Width/2;
    float y = (float)(center.Y + radius * Math.Sin(Math.PI + (Math.PI * i / numberOfItems)))-iconBmp.Height/2;

    canvas.DrawBitmap(iconBmp, new SKPoint(x, y));
}
```

Comment: All programming questions are math questions. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I see I was on the right track :D I already tried removing the 2*Math.PI with just Math.PI but didn't see that I have to add Math.PI+ then.

I was about to ask that question in the math boar but then thought I would prefer an answer in code so I posted it here.

How could I tweak the code now in order to start the items for example at -75 degrees instead of -90?

Comment: Ok thx with your solution I figured how to display it as I want/need it :) 
My final solution is 

```float x = (float)(center.X + radius * Math.Cos(Math.PI + (Math.PI/2/numberOfItems) + (Math.PI * i / numberOfItems))) - iconBmp.Width / 2;```

```float y = (float)(center.Y + radius * Math.Sin(Math.PI + (Math.PI/2/numberOfItems) + (Math.PI * i / numberOfItems))) - iconBmp.Height / 2;```

Comment: `pi = 180 deg`, so if you want to start at `-75 deg` instead of `-90 deg`, then add `15 deg`. Which is `(pi * 15 / 180)`.

Comment: What you've put in your comment will change the start point depending on how many points there are. Nothing wrong with that, but I just wanted to make sure that was what you intended for it to do.